# Azure App Authentication Extension doesn't work with UWP apps?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, authentication, azure-keyvault

I've been trying out the new [Azure App Authentication Extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/17/managing-secrets-securely-in-the-cloud/) to securely access the Azure Key Vault. The blogs and docs make it seem like it's squarely geared toward web services, but since there's a .NET NuGet, I assumed it would work for UWP apps, too. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a trivial implementation to work in UWP.

The code below **works fine** in a .NET Core console app, but in a simple UWP app the awaited statement throws an error:

`using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;`

`using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;`

```
private async Task GetKeyVaultInfoAsync()
{
    AzureServiceTokenProvider azureTokenManager =
                              new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

    KeyVaultClient keyVaultManager = new KeyVaultClient(
                   new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureTokenManager.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    // Error occurs here in UWP
    SecretBundle keyInfo = await keyVaultManager.GetSecretAsync(
                           $"https://{KeyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/Secrets/{Key}");

    string keyValue = keyInfo.Value;
}
```

> ```
> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureTokenServiceProviderException:
>   Connectionstring: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource: https://vault.azure.net,
>   Authority: https://login.windows.net/[GUID],
>   Exception Message:
>      Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity.
>      Tried to get token using Visual Studio.
>      Tried to get token using Azure CLI.
>      Access token could not be acquired.
> ```

Does Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication **not** work with UWP or am I missing something?

Comment: I try to reprouce this issue on my side.  But I get the exception in your mentioned code line `One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.` Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: Make sure you've defined the constants {KeyVaultName} and {Key} in your code consistent with how your key vault is set up. Your error sounds like it can't find the key vault.

Comment: It seems that it is not related to {KeyVaultName} and {Key}, as it has the correct value.

Comment: Interesting: I get the same error as originally posted at the same code location when using the Azure App Authentication Extension in a Service Fabric app. Sounds like some Microsoft systems aren't yet compatible with the new capabilities.